# Cardinality of the set of functions from N to {0,1,2,3,...,9} is equal to card(R)

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

I know that the set of infinite sequences on {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} is uncountable, but how to show that it has a bijection to R?

Comment: Hint:  if $f$ is such a function then make a real number between $0$ and $1$ using the values of $f$ as decimal digits, as in $.f(1)f(2)f(3).....$

Comment: Note that constructing an explicit bijection is difficult because the well-known phenomenon concerning decimal representations with trailing $9$'s. It's easier to construct two injections, one in each direction.

Comment: @Arthur That's exactly what I'm concerned with, how can I construct an injection from (0,1) to the infinite sequences?

Comment: @JJTsai Pick a number, use binary representation, and if it has a terminating expansion use that one rather than the trailing $1$-expansion. Then that gives a nice injection to the set of functions. An injection the other way can be given by interpreting the function as a decimal expansion base eleven or more.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks I got the first part! But what exactly is a decimal expansion base eleven or more?

Comment: Pick a number greater than or equal to eleven, and use that as your base. That means you have available symbols other than $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$. Of course, they won't be used. That's what makes it an injection: the number $0.49999\ldots$ becomes something other than $0.500000\ldots$, in contrast to base-ten.

Comment: @Arthur But how can you be sure that there aren't repeating representations in the new expansion?

Comment: @JJTsai There are repeating representations, but since none of the digits we have available are exactly one less than the base we use, none of the repeating decimals touch upon the "$0.999\ldots =1$"-phenomenon. That means that the repeating-zeroes numbers get to be alone, which is exactly where injective would have failed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple answer if you know enough of the basic cardinality theorems:

$$|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}\le 10^{\aleph_0}\le (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\times\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\Bbb R|$$